# Эта версия приложения не работает с платёжной системой Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Пишу приложение с внутриигровыми покупками.
Приложение работает без ошибок - осталось протестирвоать покупку.
Запускаю приложение на телефоне (устанавливаю через Android Studio, не через Play Market), пытаюсь осуществить покупку и получаю сообщение - "Эта версия приложения не работает не работает с платёжной системой Google Play ..."

Помогите разобраться, где ошибка.

Comment: Может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469253/5698345

Comment: У вас на телефоне версия с тем же ключом собрана, что и в Google Play? Версия та же?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11068686/4928642

Comment: Спасибо Всем! Да, проблема была в том, сто на телефоне запускал не подписанную версию и не опубликованную в Gogle Play.